# Connect to an online db in c++

Tags: c++, database

I created my database in phpMyAdmin from godaddy.com.
But i can't seem to find a way to connect to it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "cppconn/driver.h"
#include "cppconn/exception.h"
#include "cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "cppconn/statement.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "mysqlcppconn.lib")

const string server   = "myWebsite";
const string username = "username";
const string password = "password";

int main()
{
    sql::Driver     *driver; 
        sql::Connection *dbConn;
        sql::Statement  *stmt;  
        sql::ResultSet  *res;   

    try
    {
        driver = get_driver_instance();
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "Could not get a database driver. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    try
    {
        dbConn = driver->connect(server, username, password);
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "Could not connect to database. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    stmt = dbConn->createStatement();

    try
    {
        stmt->execute("USE test");

        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");

    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "SQL error. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }


    sql::ResultSetMetaData *res_meta = res -> getMetaData();
    int columns = res_meta -> getColumnCount();

    while (res->next())
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                cout << res->getString(i) << " | " ;
                }
         cout << endl;
    }

    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete dbConn;
    return 0;
}
```

But i get this error:

> **Could not connect to database. Error message: Access denied for user 'username'@'IP' (using password: YES)**

This code works fine with the local phpmyadmin databases.

So is there any different way to connect to databases that are hosted on a website?

Comment: Database connection can be configured to reject remote connections and only allow local connections, have you check this?  The standard MySQL security script (if run) defaults to only allowing local connections.

Comment: @RichardCritten Remote connections are allowed. Is it possible that my mistake is that i'm initialising string server = "myWebsite" domain? could it be something else?